# Convert column of a pandas dataframe from string to list type

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataframe 'df' in which one column contains list which is of data type string.I need to convert it into list or bring the list out from string.
The following is my dataframe.

```
  UId     Genres 
427256          ['Comedy', 'Drama', 'Science Fiction']      
427259          ['Crime', 'Action', 'Science Fiction']     
427260                         ['Animation', 'Family']         
427265                                      ['Comedy']       
427266                                      ['Comedy']           
427270                                      ['Comedy']         
427277                                      ['Comedy']
```

type(df.iloc[0]['Genres']) is String.

Comment: Use literal eval `import ast ; df['Genres'] = df['Genres'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank you so much :)

Comment: What to do when this Genre column, contains NaN. ast.literal_eval is unable to handle it

Comment: @Dark Worked perfectly for me. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: BTW, can I get some link which can explain me how above line of code is working perfectly for the mentioned problem.